# Failed to submit app from Xcode 5.1.1 ***-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] nil arguments**

Tags: xcode5, ios7.1

[image]

I am trying to upload my app to appstore through Xcode 5.1.1 as follows - created an archive then from organiser i tried distribute-> submit to IOS App Store after that i selected distribution provisioning profile which i created earlier it went through the process but stopped and gave me the error like  ***-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] nil arguments** though i don't have any string declared in the code. I just have 4 buttons on the viewcontroller. I had tried the same with xcode 5.1.0 but the  error was something different like - ERROR ITMS-9000: This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App store must be built with public(GM) version of XCode 5.1.1 so i updated my xcode version, but here am not getting anything about this i googled at my best. Please give me some suggestions or ideas about this error am stuck here badly.

Comment: Yeah for me too coming... I am unable to submit my build. Any one knows why is that?

Comment: I could resolve this myself by first submitting app from other macbook, but later on i could do it from my iMac as well by downloading and installing latest application loader version from itunes it resolved my issue. Just try it.

Comment: Great , Yes I did the same  and submitted. Now , its in waiting for review :) Thanks Mak

Comment: your welcome Meenu :)

Comment: Mak , Its been 6 days. But , still my app is in waiting for review....Other than to wait , any other solution ?? :(

Comment: @Meenu : Don't worry sometime it takes more time than expected even my app is also in review state since june 10th. Better lets wait for some more days.